# Python, Django, Tutorial, Testing Detail View, Error

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am making way through the Django tutorials, and have stumbled into error on my part in tutorial 5 > 'Testing the Detail View'

When I run:

`python manage.py test polls`

in the terminal, I am greeted with this message:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.F.......
======================================================================
FAIL: test_detail_view_with_a_past_question (polls.tests.QuestionIndexDetailTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/theoford/Documents/python/04_django_intro/mysite/polls/tests.py", line 115, in test_detail_view_with_a_past_question
    status_code=200)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 398, in assertContains
    msg_prefix + "Couldn't find %s in response" % text_repr)
AssertionError: Couldn't find 'Past Question.' in response

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.030s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

This is the code I have within tests.py in relation to the 'testing the detail view with a past question' (it is the latter of the functions).

```
class QuestionIndexDetailTests(TestCase):
    def test_detail_view_with_a_future_question(self):
        """
        The detail view of a question with a pub_date in the future should
        return a 404 not found.
        """
        future_question = create_question(question_text='Future question.',
                                          days=5)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:detail',
                                   args=(future_question.id,)))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)

    def test_detail_view_with_a_past_question(self):
        """
        The detail view of a question with a pub_date in the past should
        display the question's text.
        """
        past_question = create_question(question_text='Past Question.',
                                        days=-5)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:detail',
                                   args=(past_question.id,)))
        self.assertContains(response, past_question.question_text,
                            status_code=200)
```

I am new to the Stackoverflow community, so I apologise if the formatting and phraising of this question is incorrect, incomplete or inappropriate, yet any help on advancing from this problem would be greatly appreciated.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone 

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions (not including those published in the future)."""
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question 
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question 
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: Can you show the view? The problem may be there.

Comment: Sure - just added it to question

Comment: debug it... put `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` before calling `test_detail_view_with_a_past_question()` it will pause the test and give you a shell to inspect your code... in that shell do 
`Question.objects.all()` check the dates... you could even go "step by step" with `n` or "step into" using `s`

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to check that 'Past Question.' is in `response.content`, not `response`. Change the last line of `test_detail_view_with_a_past_question` to be:

```
self.assertContains(response.content, past_question.question_text,
                        status_code=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case test cases have passed in 2 ways:

1. by adding attribute pk_url_kwargs to the DetailView in views.py with the value of 'question_id'

   pk_url_kwargs = 'question_id'

or

2. by changing the 'question_id' in the urls.py to the 'pk'

   path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

reason:

As far as I understand generic DetailView looks up for an object according to parameter named 'pk' or 'slug' by default -- (pick up an object whose primary key is equal to the value of variable named 'pk'), but in tutorial in urls.py additional integer argument is named as 'question_id' so we need to change pk_url_kwargs in views.py or name of argument in urls.py.